# How to hide the ListRow in Android Tv Leanback Library

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

[image]

I am new to android Leanback and I am following the google samples to learn Leanback to build android tv apps. I have following question:

Suppose if I am fetching the data for the row marked in the ****Image attached** above** from backend. If the data is empty, how to hide the Row from the BrowseSupportFragment. The rest of the rows should be visible. How to use View.GONE on specific row on runtime.

*Disclaimer: I do not own the image I am using above. It is the property of https://github.com/android/tv-samples page and I am using it for learning purposes.*

Answer (score 0):

The content in the BrowseSupportFragment comes from an [ObjectAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/widget/ObjectAdapter). The best way to handle the change you've described is to update the adapter's underlying data and call notifyItemRangeRemoved. The adapter also has notifyItemRangeChanged, notifyItemMoved, and notifyItemRangeInserted to use in cases where the data changes (e.g., you still have the same shows but maybe the thumbnails have changed), the data moves (e.g., the first row gets moved to the bottom of the list), or there's new data (e.g., a completely new row is added at the bottom).

Using the notify* methods is the best way to handle changes because they allow for much more efficient updates. In cases where the data is entirely different (or you can't meaningfully determine what has changed), you can assign a new ObjectAdapter with a completely different set of data. Just know that doing that is less efficient and can result in jank/jumpiness in the UI.